# Show mouse cursor in phantom.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to show mouse cursor in phantomjs when taking screenshot (capture)?

I am trying to use below to move mouse to XY position

```
sendEvent(mouseEventType[, mouseX, mouseY, button='left'])
```

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/

But I am not sure if it works because the hover effect didn't show.

Answer (score 1):

The hover effect is supposed to show, you probably have an error in the coordinates you're passing which isn't really over the element you're looking for.

Although, you won't be able to capture a screenshot with the mouse cursor, since the cursor actually belongs to the OS and not to the browser. phantomjs simulates the browser, just without rendering it.

Comment: Is there a way to show some dot or something just to debug? I changed coordinate and couldn't troubleshoot why hover didn't work. Some workaround is fine

Comment: Not that i know of. Like i said, the phantomjs is just a browser, and it sends the browser the events, but doesn't effect the OS (e.g.: actual mouse movement). Try printing out the element's position you're looking to hover above, and then see if this matches the position you're sending.